# Error al ejecutar el comando DBCC SHRINKFILE en el Archivo Log de una base de datos SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

El siguiente código sql para la compactación del log:

```
use My_dabase
go

declare 
@arch_log sysname

set @arch_log =(select name FROM SYSFILES
                where fileid = '2')

select name from sysfiles

ALTER DATABASE My_database
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
    DBCC SHRINKFILE (@arch_log , 2);
ALTER DATABASE My_database
SET RECOVERY FULL
```

... Me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
'Cannot shrink log file 2 (My_database_Log) because total number of logical log files cannot be fewer than 2.'
```

He tratado de indagar y abrir un sin fin de páginas relacionadas con el problema pero no entiendo muy bien los conceptos del VLF's ni mucho menos puedo relacionarlos con el problema en concreto que tengo. ¿Cómo debería manejar este error? ¿Está mal plantedo el script?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu script es correcto, pero según lo que te indica el error el archivo de log contiene el mínimo de VLFs por lo que ya no pueden reducirse.

Te explico, cada archivo físico de log está dividido internamente en partes más pequeñas llamadas *Virtual Log File* (VLF), la cantidad y tamaño de estos archivos virtuales lo determina el Motor, y son utilizados de manera secuencial y circular.

```
        logfile.ldf
+----+----+----+----+----+
|VLF1|VLF2|VLF3|....|VLFN|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Se van utilizando los VLF a medida que se necesite y se marcar como disponibles los que ya dejan de ser útiles (Generalmente al hacer un backup del log en BD en modo fullrecovery). Cuando llena el último VLF empieza a reutilizar los del principio si están disponibles. Si no, se produce un incremento del tamaño de Log físico para generar nuevos VLFs.

Así tu puedes tener un archivo físico de log de digamos 10MB el cual internamente tendría 4 VLF de 2,5MB por ejemplo. Suponiendo que dos VLF aún contengan información útil y dos estén disponibles, se podría llegar a reducir el archivo físico de log en 5MB eliminando los dos VFL "libres".

En caso de que necesites reducir sí o sí el tamaño del log puedes intentar lo que indican [aquí](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/38990e25-c46b-462a-9be3-a9026bafac38/shrink-log-file-have-problem?forum=databasedesign#63fe5dfb-2ee4-432b-963e-7a5bfc698df4), aunque generalmente el log crece hasta alcanzar el tamaño que necesita el motor para poder trabajar:

- Crear un nuevo archivo de log para uso temporal.
- Vaciar el archivo de log original: `dbcc shrinkfile(2, emptyfile) --My_database_log tiene id 2 según el mensaje de error`
  al vaciar el log con id2 el contenido pasa al archivo de log recien creado.
- Achicar el log original ya vacío.
- Establecer el tamaño del log orignal a uno apropiado, esto dependería de tu caso puntual.
- Vaciar el log temporal, para volcar el contenido al archivo del log original: `dbcc shrinkfile(3, emptyfile)` y removerlo.
- Volvel a ejecutar el `shrinkfile`